# How to (hermetically) include Python interpreter in Bazel to build Python library (sdist)

Tags: python, bazel

How can I (hermetically) include `python` as an (executable) input to my `genrule`?

Conceptually, I'm aware of the following approaches:

- [include a python interpreter in the source repo at `third_party/python`](https://github.com/abergmeier-dsfishlabs/bazel_hermetic_test)
- have Bazel fetch python ala [`rules-go`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/WORKSPACE#L9)

There also seem to be a couple methods for doing so:

- [`py_runtime`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/python.html#py_runtime)
- [`py_toolchain`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/pull/82#issue-178199739) (doesn't seem to be available yet)
- [`py_distribution_package`](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dQjbbLEJqxUIJWmH5sIZAv-_emnKksDI-VCG1v86dWA/edit#heading=h.79c87s8bgvsc) (doesn't seem to be available yet)
- [`genrules.tools`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule_args)
- [`genrules.toolchains`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule_args)

---

Example:

I have a python library:

```
myproject
- setup.py
- mylibrary
  - __init__.py
  - myfunction.py
```

I'd like to produce a `pip install`-able distribution with [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) so that I can do:

```
pip install <path/to/distribution>
python
>>> from mylibrary.myfunction import helloworld
>>> helloworld()
```

I added a (empty) `WORKSPACE` file at `myproject/WORKSPACE` and followed the example in [this medium article](https://medium.com/@nqbao/first-try-with-bazel-747a59d64187):

```
# myproject/BUILD
genrule(
    name = "mylibrary_sdist",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.py"]),
    outs = ["mylibrary.tar.gz"],
    cmd = "python setup.py sdist && mv dist/mylibrary*.tar.gz $(location mylibrary.tar.gz)"
)
```

This works (ie. produces `bazel-genfiles/mylibrary.tar.gz`), but I'm shelling out to `python`.

How can I (hermetically) include `python` as an (executable) input to my `genrule`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this should just be a matter of passing the actual path to your target python executable. I would check the python executable into the `third_party` dir and instead of invoking your genrule using simply `python` I'd pass the relative path to that executable relative to `WORKSPACE`.

Comment: what would I do if I want the bazel build to work cross-platform? I could include the compiled `python` interpreter in `third_party` as you state, but then it'd be compiled for a specific architecture. Is the best practice to include compiled versions for the architectures you want? Or I could include the source for python and have the compilation of the interpreter as part of my bazel build

Comment: Well, my first instinct would be to say not to provide cross-platform support unless you really need it. But if you do need to, I'd probably start by checking in compiled executives for the relevant platforms - you can then leverage Bazel's [platform variables](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/platforms.html) to help Bazel reference the specific executable for the relevant host platform at build time.

Comment: I don't think there's much upside in including the source for Python and compiling it as part of your build. If you think you're going to need to support a very large range of platforms, then that could be an option. But I'd start simple - pick a specific list of architectures / platforms you want to support, grab those executables, and check them in / link them.